# Variable element string matching in Oracle 11g

Tags: regex, oracle

I wrote a regex using a positive lookbehind, but Oracle can't use lookbehinds, so I'm sort of at a loss.

```
//test string without suffix
Last_name, First_name Middle_initial:(some_other_unimportant_stuff)

//test string with suffix
Last_name Suffix, First_name Middle_initial:(some_other_unimportant_stuff)
```

I'm attempting to parse some data out of table using the following query:

```
SELECT 
   regexp_substr(displayname,'[^,]*') AS last_name,
   regexp_substr(displayname,'(?<=,)[^\]]+\s') AS first_name,
   upper(substr(regexp_substr(displayname,'[A-Za-z]:'),0,1)) AS middle_initial
FROM table
```

I'm able to get the `last_name` and `middle initial`, but the `first_name` is causing me issues.  Any idea on how to rewrite the regex to grab the first name, or use the baked in oracle functions to accomplish the same thing? TIA

Comment: Try `regexp_substr(au.displayname, ',\s*(\w+)\s', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`. This will work when there is a space and when there is no space before the first name.

Comment: Don't forget to take into consideration the fact that names can have special characters in them like single-quotes, spaces, hyphens, etc. Could throw a monkey-wrench into your parsing algorithm.  Make sure to test carefully.  Do some sanity checks on your data first to make sure what kind of data you'll have to deal with.  Hopefully some scrubbing happened on the input side so you won't have to deal with anything too crazy (yeah, right).

Comment: @Gary_W  I agree, but I already know what the values are going to be, and this is part of a larger one time import.  These values have been supplied by the client, so I don't believe that they will be changing from the original data that was sent.  Any additional users will be added through the application that is is supporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that may allow for easier maintenance as the regex is the same. Break the line down into it's components by grouping them, then select the groups you want for each element. Note the separators are not grouped. It will not work if the first_name has a space in it though.

```
    SQL> with tbl(str) as (
           select 'Last_name, First_name Middle_initial:(some_other_unimportant_stuff)' from dual union
           select 'Last_name Suffix, First_name Middle_initial:(some_other_unimportant_stuff)' from dual
    )
    select regexp_substr(str, '(.*?), (.*?) (.*?):', 1, 1, NULL, 1) Last,
           regexp_substr(str, '(.*?), (.*?) (.*?):', 1, 1, NULL, 2) First,
           regexp_substr(str, '(.*?), (.*?) (.*?):', 1, 1, NULL, 3) Middle
    from tbl;

    LAST               FIRST           MIDDLE
    ------------------ --------------- ---------------
    Last_name Suffix   First_name      Middle_initial
    Last_name          First_name      Middle_initial

    SQL>
```

EDIT: Updated per new name requirements.  I scrapped having the regex's all be the same, instead tightening them up somewhat by anchor them to the beginning of the string.  For the last name, return the group followed by a comma-space.  First name is the group surrounded by a comma-space and a space and lastly the middle name is the group of characters surrounded by the last space and a colon. The question mark makes the group optional so it should handle a NULL first name as seen in the test data.  As usual, test for the unexpected!

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
        select 'Last_name, First_name Middle_initial:(some_other_unimportant_stuff)' from dual union
        select 'Last_name Suffix, First_name Middle_initial:(some_other_unimportant_stuff)' from dual union
        select 'Doe1, D John:(...)' from dual union
        select 'Doe2, John D James:(...)' from dual union
        select 'Doe3, Jane:(...)' from dual
     )
     select regexp_substr(str, '^(.*?), ',    1, 1, NULL, 1) Last,
            regexp_substr(str, '^.*, (.*?) ', 1, 1, NULL, 1) First,
            regexp_substr(str, '^.* (.*?):',  1, 1, NULL, 1) Middle
     from tbl;

LAST               FIRST           MIDDLE
------------------ --------------- ---------------
Doe1               D               John
Doe2               John D          James
Doe3                               Jane
Last_name Suffix   First_name      Middle_initial
Last_name          First_name      Middle_initial

SQL>
```

Comment: So I tested this out, and I noticed that some people have names like, `Doe, D John:(...)` with `John` being the middle name, and another being like `Doe, John D James(...)`.  My regex didn't pick those up, but this one did. thanks!

Comment: I've noticed another issue.  A few users don't have middle initials, like `Doe, John:(...)`.  Your regex returns nulls for all three values.  Any idea?

Comment: Those sound like data entry errors.  You may want to put a test in there if the first name is a single letter and the middle is greater than 1 letter then reverse them or reject it.  Be care of your assumptions!  Idea: Make the select in my example above another CTE (the WITH statement) and select from that, analyzing the first name and middle initial, reversing if the first is one letter and the middle is > than one letter. NULL middle wasn't in the original specs.  :-/ Let me try...

Comment: What output would you expect with 'Doe, John D James:(...)'?

Comment: @RobM Updated. Please give the new version a try. What would no Middle look like?

Comment: So I basically just nulled the middle name,the application, it's only seen in one place.  Additionally, this was an initial load of new users, and their information get's updated via Active Directory, so that should work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle regex does not support lookarounds. However, you may resort to *capturing groups* and access their values:

```
regexp_substr(au.displayname, ',\s*([A-Za-z]+)\s', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS first_name
```

Here, the capturing group is defined with `(....)` and the last `1` tells `regexp_substr` to only output this subvalue.

Here is [how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/F1a0pf/1) (I added `_` to match the placeholders provided in the OP).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
//the regex for First_name
\s[A-Za-z]+
```

which got me

```
, First_name
```

The query now looks like:

```
SELECT 
    regexp_substr(displayname,'[^,]*') AS last_name,
    trim(substr(regexp_substr(au.displayname,',\s[A-Za-z]+'),2)) AS first_name,
    upper(substr(regexp_substr(displayname,'[A-Za-z]:'),0,1)) AS middle_initial 
FROM table
```